# How to add one column to Datagridview (which had been filled by datasource)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 datagridviews. I call method `CellContentClick` which has to the other datagridview using DB. And I have to add another column to the second datagridview and fill it.

How I fill the second datagridview:

```
//Connetion to Access DB 
const string strProvider =
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase v1.3.accdb";

// Query to DB
var strSql = "SELECT * FROM [Проф прививки] WHERE id_ученика=" + dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

var con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
var scores = new DataTable();
da.Fill(scores);
dataGridView3.DataSource = scores;
```

So, it works fine...

But if I add a new column to datagridview by designer and fill with data, the column is not filled.

How I fill a new column:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //Query to the other table
    strSql = "SELECT [Название прививки] FROM [Список прививок] WHERE [id_тип_прививки]=" +
    (int) dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;

    //Use method GetFromDb which returns the selection
    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = GetFromDb(strSql, 0);
}
```

So, the column is empty, but if I write `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());`
I will see filled data.

And if I call method `CellContentClick` another time, I will see that column filled.

**UPD:**
The full code:

```
public void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {try
        {
            const string strProvider =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase v1.3.accdb";
            var strSql = "SELECT * FROM [Проф прививки] WHERE id_ученика=" +
                         dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            var con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            var scores = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(scores);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = scores;

            //подтягиваем заболевания
            for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                strSql = "SELECT [Название прививки] FROM [Список прививок] WHERE [id_тип_прививки]=" +
                         (int) dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = GetFromDb(strSql, 0);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Ошибка! " + ex.Message);
        }
```

}

```
public string GetFromDb(string query, int num)
    {
        var result = "";
        var conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase v1.3.accdb";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result = dr.GetValue(num).ToString();

            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + @" : " + ex.StackTrace, @"Load Error");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You better learn to use parameters for your queries to avoid sql injection.  So, the data is there, but you can't see it?  If you added the column from the designer, presumably, wouldn't that make it Cell[0] since it's the first column created?

Comment: Yes, the data is there, but i can`t see when i call the first time method. After the second time i see all columns filled. 
I relplace the column that`s why it`s not Cell[0].

Comment: What event are you using when you fill that column?  You should probably show us that entire method.

Comment: You probably want CellClick instead of CellContentClick.  CellContentClick requires the user to actually click on the text part of the cell, and not just in the cell.  Are you doing anything with CellPainting?  If you minimize the form and then restore it, do you *then* see the data in the column?

Comment: No, i don`t use CellPainting.
The first time i clicked to the cell (upper datagrid) - http://prntscr.com/9y4xc0
The second time i clicked - http://prntscr.com/9y4xsb